# Artemis support as StompBrokerRelay in Spring UserDestination

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I was able to connect Artemis as StompBrokerRelay successfully but i had to use

```
config.setPathMatcher(new AntPathMatcher("."));
```

And all my queues start with

```
jms.queue.xxxx
```

When i tried to send private messages to users using the /user/ Destination it did not work and the reason for this is **DefaultUserDestinationResolver** as i described [here in jira bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14044) is hard coded to search for '/' and leave leading / so if i try sending to /user/xxxx/jms.queue.call it will be translated into /jms.queue.call while for it to work it should go to jms.queue.call

Is it possible to override the **[DefaultUserDestinationResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d5ee787e1e6653257720afe31ee3f8819cd4605c/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/simp/user/DefaultUserDestinationResolver.java)** used in **[AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/68f6cf9d3a2c9dace624fffc93473d91772df14e/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/simp/config/AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration.java)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in version 4.3 RC1 per the above [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14044)